# Цикл для ввода даты

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать цикл для ввода даты, чтобы он предлагал ввести значение из диапазона до тех пор, пока не будет введено это значение правильно.

```
import random
from datetime import datetime

start_date = datetime.strptime("01.01.2016", "%d.%m.%Y")
end_date = datetime.strptime("01.01.2019", "%d.%m.%Y")
x = random.randint(-30, 30)
while True:
     prompt = "Input a date from the range [{:%d.%m.%Y} - {:%d.%m.%Y}]: ".format(start_date, end_date)
     try:
         user_date = datetime.strptime(input(prompt), "%d.%m.%Y")
         if start_date <= user_date <= end_date:
             break
         if user_date >= end_date or user_date <= start_date:
             print("Please, select date from 01.01.2016 to 01.01.2019")
     except ValueError:
         print("Please enter a correct date")
print(f'User_date: {user_date:%d.%m.%Y}')
print("What a forecast do you want to see?")
print("1)Weather today")
print("2)Weather in 3 days")
print("3)Weather in 5 days")
print("4)Weather in 7 days")
while True:
    a1 = int(input("Weather:\n>"))
    try:
        if a1 == 1:
            if (start_date <= user_date <= end_date):
                print(x)
                break
        if a1 == 2:
            if (start_date <= user_date <= end_date):
                print(x * 3)
                break
        if a1 == 3:
            if (start_date <= user_date <= end_date):
                print(x * 5)
                break
        if a1 == 4:
            if (start_date <= user_date <= end_date):
                print(x * 7)
                break
        if a1 < 1 or a1 > 4:
            print("Please, select position from 1 to 4!")
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a correct number")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
def inp_dt_from_range(start_date, end_date):
    while True:
        prompt = "Input a date from the range [{:%d.%m.%Y} - {:%d.%m.%Y}]: " \
                 .format(start_date, end_date)

        try:
            user_date = datetime.strptime(input(prompt), "%d.%m.%Y")
            if start_date <= user_date <= end_date:
                break
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return user_date

def choose_int_option(text, prompt, options=[1,2,3]):
    print(text)
    while True:
        try:
            ret = int(input(prompt))
            if ret in options:
                return ret
        except ValueError:
            pass


text = """
What a forecast do you want to see?
1) Weather today
2) Weather in 3 days
3) Weather in 5 days
4) Weather in 7 days"""

user_date = inp_dt_from_range(start_date, end_date)
opt_range = list(range(1,5))
prompt = f'Input an integer from within a range: {opt_range}: '
opt = choose_int_option(text, prompt, opt_range)
```

Пример:

```
In [7]: user_date = inp_dt_from_range(start_date, end_date)
   ...: opt_range = list(range(1,5))
   ...: prompt = f'Input an integer from within a range: {opt_range}: '
   ...: opt = choose_int_option(text, prompt, opt_range)
Input a date from the range [01.01.2016 - 01.01.2019]: asasa
Input a date from the range [01.01.2016 - 01.01.2019]: 11.11.2018

What a forecast do you want to see?
1) Weather today
2) Weather in 3 days
3) Weather in 5 days
4) Weather in 7 days
Input an integer from within a range: [1, 2, 3, 4]: qwq
Input an integer from within a range: [1, 2, 3, 4]: 0
Input an integer from within a range: [1, 2, 3, 4]: 2

In [8]: print(f'user_date: {user_date:%d.%m.%Y}\topt: {opt}')
user_date: 11.11.2018   opt: 2
```

---

**Ответ на вопрос *до редактирования*:**

```
In [9]: while True:
   ...:     prompt = "Input a date from the range [{:%d.%m.%Y} - {:%d.%m.%Y}]: " \
   ...:              .format(start_date, end_date)
   ...:
   ...:     try:
   ...:         user_date = datetime.strptime(input(prompt), "%d.%m.%Y")
   ...:         if start_date <= user_date <= end_date:
   ...:             break
   ...:     except ValueError:
   ...:         pass
   ...:
   ...: print(f'user_date: {user_date:%d.%m.%Y}')
```

Вывод:

```
Input a date from the range [01.01.2016 - 01.01.2019]: ababa
Input a date from the range [01.01.2016 - 01.01.2019]: 01.15.2018
Input a date from the range [01.01.2016 - 01.01.2019]: 31.12.2018
user_date: 31.12.2018
```

Comment: Максим, можно вопрос? Обновил пост..

Comment: В последнем цикле, при вводе любых символов кроме цифр выводится ошибка в терминале, а не сообщение print("Please enter a correct number"). Подскажите, что я упустил?

Comment: @Deefrost, дополнил ответ

Answer (score 2):

```
import datetime

start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("01.01.2016", "%d.%m.%Y")
end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("01.01.2019", "%d.%m.%Y")

user_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("01.01.2010", "%d.%m.%Y")    # вне диапазона

while not start_date < user_date < end_date:   # или <= (как вам надо)
    user_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(input("Choose date: \n"), "%d.%m.%Y")
```